# How to use speech recognition to get voice input from user?

Tags: python, input, speech-recognition

```
enter code here

sr = s.Recognizer()
print(''' listening...
speak the first card''')

with s.Microphone() as m:
    audio = sr.listen(m)
    query = sr.recognize_google(audio, language='eng-in')

first_card = input("Enter the first card: ")
second_card = input("Enter the second card: ")
third_card = input("Enter the third card: ")
fourth_card = input("Enter the fourth card: ")
print("the upnext cards are", fourth_card, third_card, second_card, first_card)
```

I want user to voice input the first card, second card and so on instead of typing them with keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the following in a while loop (see the end of the answer for full code) you can get the voice input from the user the desired number of times by appending each time to a list.

```
with s.Microphone() as m:
    audio = sr.listen(m)
    query = sr.recognize_google(audio)
    cards.append(query) #where cards is the list of user inputted cards
```

Note, sometimes there will be an unrecognised input, which is why the example below uses a counter that increments when we have a successful voice input recognised (if we get to the end of the 'try' part, we know that the input has been recognised).

Obviously sometimes this will not recognise the voice input accurately, you could show the user what 'query' is and get them to confirm this is correct/allow them to retry (although in my testing the voice input is pretty much accurate all the time).

```
import speech_recognition as s

cards = []
numberOfCards = 4

validInputs = 0

while validInputs < numberOfCards: 
    sr = s.Recognizer()
    with s.Microphone() as m:
        print("Speak for card", (validInputs + 1), ":")
        audio = sr.listen(m)

    try:
        query = sr.recognize_google(audio)
        print("card", (calidInputs + 1), ":", query)
        cards.append(query)
        validInputs += 1
    except s.UnknownValueError:
        print("unknown input, please try again")
    except s.RequestError as e:
        print("couldn't get results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))

print("the upnext cards are", cards[3], cards[2], cards[1], cards[0])
```

Running this will output:

```
Speak for card 1:
card 1: red
Speak for card 2:
card 2: green
Speak for card 3:
card 3: blue
Speak for card 4:
card 4: yellow
the upnext cards are yellow blue green red
>>>
```

which I believe is what you are trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import speech_recognition as s

cards = 0
while cards < 4:  # Change this number value as many speech input you like
    sr = s.Recognizer()
    with s.Microphone() as m:
        print(f"Speak the #{cards + 1} card \nListening... ")
        audio = sr.listen(m)
    try:
        query = sr.recognize_google(audio, language='eng-in')
        cards += 1
    except s.RequestError:
        print("API unavailable")
    except s.UnknownValueError:
        print("Unable to recognize speech. Try again.")
    if cards == 1:
        first_card = query
        continue
    if cards == 2:
        second_card = query
        continue
    if cards == 3:
        third_card = query
        continue
    if cards == 4:
        fourth_card = query
        break
    # Add more as many value referred by number in the beginning of 'while' block

print(f"the upnext cards are {fourth_card}, {third_card}, {second_card}, {first_card}")
```

It will assign the `query` string matches your names variable.

Output:

```
Speak the #1 card 
Listening... 
Speak the #2 card 
Listening... 
Unable to recognize speech. Try again. 
Speak the #2 card 
Listening... 
Speak the #3 card 
Listening... 
Speak the #4 card 
Listening... 
Unable to recognize speech. Try again.
Speak the #4 card 
Listening... 
the upnext cards are four, three, two, one

Process finished with exit code 0
```